# Front: ACF copy date from one field to another with jquery

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui, datepicker, advanced-custom-fields

I have three fields created via ACF with Datepicker: event start date, event end date and survey start date.

What I want to achieve is when I set date via datepicker on event start date, then this date is copied to event end date and survey start date.

I googled almost everything and no code is working. Actually, the nearest working solution is below:

```
acf.add_action('load', function( $el ){

var $field_start_date = $el.find('.acf-field-5800010541984');
var $field_end_date = $el.find('.acf-field-5800014941985 .input-alt');

$field_start_date.change(function() {
    var $field_start_date_value = $('#acf-field_5800010541984').val();
    $('#acf-field_5800014941985').datepicker( 'setDate', $field_start_date_value );

});
```

Value is copied to another field (event end date) – attribute value is changing – but copied value doesn't show on input.

BTW, `$('#acf-field_5800014941985').datepicker('update');` doesn't work too.

Like Leeloo in The Fifth Element – "Pleeeeeeeeeeeeeese. Heeeeeeeeeeeeeelp"

Best regards,
Milosz!